# Hibernate Exception: Unable to find properties ... in entity annotated with @IdClass

Tags: java, hibernate

I have this composite key class:

```
@Embeddable
public class TaskEntityId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public String objectUuid;
    @Column(name="DOMAIN_OBJECT_UUID", nullable=false, length=36)
    public String getObjectUuid() { return objectUuid; }
    public void setObjectUuid(String uuid) { this.objectUuid = uuid; }

    public String taskName;
    @Column(name = "TASK_NAME", nullable=false, length=32)
    public String getTaskName() { return taskName; }
    public void setTaskName(String taskName) { this.taskName = taskName; }

    public Date createdTimestamp = new Date();
    @Column(name = "CREATED_TS", nullable=false, updatable=false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date getCreatedTimestamp() { return createdTimestamp; }
    public void setCreatedTimestamp(Date createdTimestamp) { this.createdTimestamp = createdTimestamp; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {...}

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {...}

    @Override
    public String toString() {...}
}
```

Which is used in this entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TASK")
@IdClass(TaskEntityId.class)
public class TaskEntity implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    TaskEntityId id;

    public TaskEntityId getId() { return id; }

    public void setId(TaskEntityId id) { this.id = id; }

...
```

I also added to this class some extra getters based on suggestions to other similar questions:

```
public String getObjectUuid() { return id.getObjectUuid(); }
public String getTaskName() { return id.getTaskName(); }
public Date getCreatedTimestamp() { return id.getCreatedTimestamp(); }
```

Still, I get this exception:

```
Error in custom provider, org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to find properties (createdTimestamp, objectUuid, taskName) in entity annotated with @IdClass:c.m.d.p.TaskEntity
```

Answer (score 13):

The solution is to remove the

```
@IdClass(TaskEntityId.class)
```

annotation from the `TaskEntity` class. And I also needed an empty default constructor.

Comment: I had been using another method of defining composite primary keys, and the first method I attempted used `@IdClass`.  When I switched to the `@EmbeddedId` method, I forgot to remove the `@IdClass` annotation, which resulted in these errors.  Once I removed the incorrect annotation, the error went away.  Good call, @Gabor-Kulcsar!

Comment: Another detail: I had put my Id class `TaskEntityId` as an inner class of `TaskEntity`, and did all of the above, and the error message was still to add an empty default constructor. I had to put it in a **separate file** (as an outer class) in order for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

To map a composite key, you can use the EmbeddedId or the IdClass annotations. I know this question is not strictly about JPA but the rules defined by the specification also applies. So here they are:

2.1.4 Primary Keys and Entity Identity

...

A composite primary key must correspond to either a single persistent field or property or to a set of such fields or properties as described below. A primary key class must be defined to represent a composite primary key. Composite primary keys typically arise when mapping from legacy databases when the database key is comprised of several columns. The EmbeddedId and  IdClass annotations are used to denote composite primary keys. See sections 9.1.14 and 9.1.15.

...

The following rules apply for composite primary keys:

The primary key class must be public and must have a public no-arg constructor.
If property-based access is used, the properties of the primary key class must be public or protected.
The primary key class must be serializable.
The primary key class must define equals and hashCode methods. The semantics of value equality for these methods must be consistent with the database equality for the database types to which the key is mapped.
A composite primary key must either be represented and mapped as an embeddable class (see Section 9.1.14, “EmbeddedId Annotation”) or must be represented and mapped to multiple fields or properties of the entity class (see Section 9.1.15, “IdClass Annotation”).
If the composite primary key class is mapped to multiple fields or properties of the entity class, the names of primary key fields or properties in the primary key class and those of the entity class must correspond and their types must be the same.

**With an IdClass**

The class for the composite primary key could look like (could be a static inner class):

```
public class TimePK implements Serializable {
    protected Integer levelStation;
    protected Integer confPathID;

    public TimePK() {}

    public TimePK(Integer levelStation, String confPathID) {
        this.id = levelStation;
        this.name = confPathID;
    }
    // equals, hashCode
}
```

And the entity:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(TimePK.class)
class Time implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Integer levelStation;
    @Id
    private Integer confPathID;

    private String src;
    private String dst;
    private Integer distance;
    private Integer price;

    // getters, setters
}
```

The IdClass annotation maps multiple fields to the table PK.

**With EmbeddedId**

The class for the composite primary key could look like (could be a static inner class):

*

```
@Embeddable
public class TimePK implements Serializable {
    protected Integer levelStation;
    protected Integer confPathID;
    public TimePK() {}
    public TimePK(Integer levelStation, String confPathID) {
        this.id = levelStation;
        this.name = confPathID;
    }
    // equals, hashCode
}
```

*
And the entity:

```
@Entity
class Time implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private TimePK timePK;

    private String src;
    private String dst;
    private Integer distance;
    private Integer price;

    //...
}
```

The @EmbeddedId annotation maps a PK class to table PK.

Differences:

From the physical model point of view, there are no differences
EmbeddedId somehow communicates more clearly that the key is a composite key and IMO makes sense when the combined pk is either a meaningful entity itself or it reused in your code.
@IdClass is useful to specify that some combination of fields is unique but these do not have a special meaning.
They also affect the way you write queries (making them more or less verbose):

with IdClass

select t.levelStation from Time t

with EmbeddedId

select t.timePK.levelStation from Time t